# Django transaction.commit() needed after Model.objects.filter() when object was saved from another process

Tags: python, mysql, django, multiprocessing

I have two processes running the Django codebase, for various reasons, one process will update an object as follows:

```
myObj.aField = "updated"
myObj.save()
```

And later on the other process attempts to read that object as follows:

```
def getObj(xxx):
   objs = TheModel.objects.filter(xyz=xxx)
   for obj in objs:
      print obj.aField
```

When reading the value from the second process, I won't see the updated value, instead I see the old value. The second time around I run the function, I do see the change.

I've noticed that if from the second process (the one reading), I change the function as follows, I get the updated value:

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def getObj(xxx):
    objs = TheModel.objects.filter(xyz=xxx)
    transaction.commit()
    for obj in objs:
        print obj.aField
```

After adding the decorator `@transaction.commit_manually` and the `transaction.commit()` line right below the `filter()` call, I do get the updated value from the field (which was saved from the other process.)

Is there any reason why this is needed? And what is the impact/potential issues of using `transaction.commit()` on a function that actually does not update models at all?
I'm not sure why it works, and if it makes sense, so hopefully someone else ran into this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: What version of Django are you using?  And are you using Django's transaction middleware?

Comment: Django 1.5, and yes, I use the transaction middleware:

Comment: Autocommit is introduced in Django 1.6.  Apparently they are aware of the issues this causes.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#autocommit

Comment: You can get autocommit turned on in earlier versions if you like, it's just not the default.

Comment: so if I enable Autocommit all these issues will magically go away? Is there any downside to running it?

Comment: Actually, never mind - the pre-1.6 autocommit is still managed at the software level.  I think you'd still have the implicit open transaction on the reading process either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using transaction middleware, each request gets a different transaction.

> The recommended way to handle transactions in Web requests is to tie them to the request and response phases via Django’s TransactionMiddleware.
>
> It works like this: When a request starts, Django starts a transaction. If the response is produced without problems, Django commits any pending transactions. If the view function produces an exception, Django rolls back any pending transactions.

This means that if the second process's request came in before the write was triggered, its transaction will predate the write.  The database will then do the right thing and report the value that was current at the time the second process's transaction was created.  Manually committing the second process's transaction before reading is harmless (as long as it has made no edits) and tells the database to create a new transaction.  Which will postdate write, and therefore give you the modified results.

Comment: I see that 1.6 removes that "recommended way" text and has the transaction management deprecated in favor of `ATOMIC_REQUESTS`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too.  Django caches the query results (which is a good thing for a single process).  If the second process has a cache of the same query, it won't see the update until the cache is flushed.

For some reason, `transaction.commit()` flushes the cache, so it helps with this problem.  Call that method right before you run your query and you should see results directly from the database.

Comment: It's more complicated than caching.  The other process almost certainly has an open transaction that predates the change in the database, so it's not the Python in-memory object that's not being updated.  The database is (correctly) returning the value for the reading process's original transaction.

Comment: Peter: if so then how do I get to "fix it"? :)
I tried adding the decorator and running transaction.commit() on the first piece of code (the one saving the model instance) but quite expectedly this didn't change anything to the second process.

Comment: It's not the writing process that needs the commit.  See my answer for a full explanation - basically the database is protecting you from having the state changed under you after the reading process starts.